# Is It possible to use a container as a service in Jenkins Pipeline?

Tags: docker, jenkins, containers

Is it possible to start a container to be **used** by one jenkins pipeline stage? For example, start a mongodb and use it in a stage configured with a docker maven agent.

Comment: Are you asking if it's possible to spin up a new container during a specific stage? Like in your example, your stage is running on a docker maven agent but you want to spin up a container with mongodb on it?

Comment: @gavsyuk Yes. Note that I don't need dind, I just want to spin up a mongo container with ports open to be used by my maven agent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only way I found to do that is to start the containers in a preparation stage to be used as a services by the other stages, and then kill them in the post section:

```
pipeline {
    agent any

    stages {

        stage('Prepare Mongo') {
            steps {
                script {
                    sh 'docker run --rm -d --name mongo mongo:<version>'
                }
            }
        }

        // Other stages, some using the mongo service.
    }

    post {
        always {
            sh 'docker stop mongo'
        }
    }
}
```

Since the docker daemon is reused, the name of the started containers should be associated to some job identification variable or some other sort of information that is unique, so avoiding container name clash.

Answer (score 1):

It is definitely possible to run Docker from a Jenkins job, while the Jenkins job is currently inside of a container.

One thing you want to make sure you are avoiding is getting into a Docker-in-Docker situation, where your container will create child containers. Instead you want your current container to create a "sibling" container.

If you look at the following blog post (written by the creator of docker-in-docker):

https://jpetazzo.github.io/2015/09/03/do-not-use-docker-in-docker-for-ci/

At the bottom there is a "The Solution" section that goes over how to give your stage containers access to your host's Docker engine. Then with access to the Docker engine you should be able to write a simple shell Docker command to spin up another container with all of the properties that you want.

Comment: The problem is that the sh command calling docker run, or the script section using docker api from Jenkins, fail because it gets executed inside the container specified by the agent section (in my example case, a maven container). I am looking for a way to spin this container as a sibling, as you mentioned, but I cannot do that from inside the stage where I already defined a container to use. Installing the client every time I enter in a stage section don't seems fine to me... and the Docker API try to find the docker command from the container.

Comment: Does it fail because you don't have Docker installed on the maven container?

Comment: Yes, exactly because of this.